# Resizing the tabbar of camera in iphone5

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, xcode4.5, uiimagepickercontroller

I've problem to resize the tabbar in camera view.
Is it possible to decrease the height of the camera tabbar in iPhone5?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a camera view presented from a `UIImagePickerController`? Because if so, no. There is no direct way to customize the action bar of of the image picker beyond adding other views on top of it. You'd probably have to create a custom capture setup using some of the stuff in [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2).